# Firebase architecture for my app

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, database-design, architecture

Here is what I want to do:

Users are getting logged in and then save data (such as thier e-mail, their work, their adress and so on). I saved this data at „/userProfile/exampleUID“. This works as I wnat it to.

Then every user should create his or her own story. Within this stories, mostly strings should be stored. A friend of mine told me, that it would be better to normalize my data, so I thought of saving the stories to „/storyData“. He also told me, that every Story has to have a unique identifier as well, which i create with .push(). Under this identifiers I want to store the users unique id (auth().currentUser.uid) to assign the story to the user who has created it. The strings for the stories should also be stored under the unique ID created by .push(). („/storyData/exampleStoryID/exampleUID“)

The problem is now that i can’t find a method to access this strings or the "/exampleUID". In this case I would need to skip the „/exampleStoryID“-child when creating a query, because without saving I would not know its name. Am I right or did I oversee the method for this?

There would be solutions to this:

I have to save the „.key“ of the „/exampleStoryID“ to the „/userProfile/exampleUID“. With this key I would not need to skip one child while querying, because I can enter this key to Access the data in /“storyData“.
I have to denormalize my data. For me, this would mean that I have to create a new child: „/userProfile/exampleUser/storyData“. Here I could save all the strings.

It may be possible that there will be more data like „/storyAnalysis“ and „/storyComments“. Having that in mind: Which solution should I prefer?

Or do you have other suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

MfG

Comment: Instead of describing your data structure, share a snippet of the actual JSON structure you intend to use (most of us find it easier to scan "code" than words). Then share the [minimal code that reproduces the use-case that you're uncertain how to implement](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). With those two items, you're more likely to get an answer. I also recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watchign [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will watch the videos you recommended. Maybe this will be enough for me to understand how i should structure it.